# How to draw samples from a multivariate Gaussian distribution without having access to a function that does the job?

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, sampling, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am using the programming language [Lua](https://www.lua.org/docs.html) which does not have any built-in function for drawing samples from a multivariate Gaussian distribution. So I wonder, how can one implement a function that does the sampling for a multivariate Gaussian distribution? Note that I do have access to a function which can draw samples from a single-variable Gaussian distribution. Can I somehow use that function to draw samples for the multivariate case given a desired covariance matrix?

Also, if I'm not mistaken, I remember I read somewhere that one can draw samples from a single-variable Gaussian distribution as follow:

$\text{sample } = \mu + \sigma^2 \epsilon$

where $\mu$ is a mean, $\sigma^2$ is a variance and $\epsilon \sim U(0,1)$. Therefore, a generalization of the above equation for a multivariate Gaussian distribution is to have mean and [diagonal] covariance matrix. However, if not sure if this equation is valid by itself and whether it gives valid samples for a non-diagonal covariance matrix.

So I wonder, can you guys give me some insights on how one should go about generating samples for a multivariate Gaussian distribution given a desired non0diagonal covariance matrix and without having having access to a built-in function in a programming language? Also, I would appreciate your help to verify/prove the equation I wrote above.

Comment: If you chose $\epsilon$ to be a vector, wouldn't $\sigma^2$ be the 2 by 2 covariance matrix?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate You're right, but I'm just not sure whether those samples are going to be valid. So can someone give some proofs or reasoning on why those samples are valid?

Comment: Your equation is wrong; that would give samples with variance $\sigma^4$. There are numerous posts already on algorithms for generating from a multivariate Gaussian distribution, for example, via a Choleski decomposition.

Comment: An example is discussed [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120179/generating-data-with-a-given-sample-covariance-matrix/120227#120227) in the paragraph beginning "In the first case...". Also see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers-given-means-variances-and-degree-of) (but which doesn't mention the mean-shift).

Comment: Also [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111865/tool-for-generating-correlated-data-sets/112160#112160) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89796/can-i-use-the-cholesky-method-for-generating-correlated-random-variables-with-gi/89830#89830)