# Conditional expectation of two continuous variables

Tags: regression, probability, self-study, conditional-probability, expected-value

So I have continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ which have $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ as their means and variances $\sigma_x^2$ and $\sigma_y^2$ and correlation $\rho$.

Find $E(Y\mid X)$.

I know that $E(Y\mid X)=\int_{R} y \left[\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}\right]dy$.

I don't understand how to find the PDFs based on the given information. I realize that this is the regression function, but I don't understand how to approach this.

Regards

Comment: Do you know the distribution of $X$ and $Y$? Such as,are they normally distributed?

Comment: @DeepNorth Knowing that $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed does not help in this problem. Knowing that $X$ and $Y$ are _jointly_ normally distributed does; cf. the answer by Vimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a homework question?  If so please tag it accordingly.

You haven't specified the probability densities for the two random variables, but if you assume a multivariate normal distribution, you can easily compute the entire conditional distribution $p(Y|X=x)$. Its expectation is simply:

$E[Y|X=x] = \mu_y + \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x} \rho (x - \mu_x)$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case.

Comment: That makes sense. Can you help me find a derivation of this. The wikipedia page just says "Proof: the result is obtained by taking the expectation of the conditional distribution X_1\mid X_2 above."

Comment: Does this have to do with $E(Y|X)=\int y(f(x,y)/f_x(x))dy$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  A brute-force way is to substitute the value of $f(x,y)$ with the formula for a bivariate normal and simplify it.  There's another clever way, which is easy to argue once you do the brute-force way.  Both approaches are described in this post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution.