# Question Regarding Zero Conditional Mean

Tags: regression, least-squares, econometrics, conditional-expectation, bivariate

Hi I am a beginner to econometrics!

I have been dealing with bivariate regression. We use the formula $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$.

I am told that if $E(u\mid x) \ne 0$ then the estimate of the slope parameter $\beta_1$ will be biased.

My question is: if $E(u\mid x) = 1$ for all $x$'s, then why would the estimate of the slope parameter be biased? I thought this would mean that only the intercept estimate will be biased.

I thought that the slope parameter will only be biased if the expected value of the errors is different for each $x$. For example if $E(u\mid x_1) = 1$ and the $E(u\mid x_2) = 3$, etc. etc.

Any help will be immensely appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the condition for **unbiasedness of the slope coefficient** is that

$$E(u \mid X) = const.$$

However, if it is different than zero, we will have **bias in the estimation of the constant term.**

If you want to go deeper, this thread may be useful, [Conditional mean independence implies unbiasedness and consistency of the OLS estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/251914/28746)

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt. I think you are confusing $X_s$ to observations $n$. There is no reason for $\beta_1$ to be biased if for all observation the $E(u|X)=1$, as that would mean you simply subtract the constant term, 1 in this case from the error term and the constant, and your equation becomes $y=\beta_0 -1 +\beta_1x + u-1$. So, your $\beta_0$ is biased but not $\beta_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what's going on:

$$\begin{align}E[\hat{\beta_1}|x] &=E\left[\frac{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{S_{xx}}\bigg|\ x\right]=\frac{1}{S_{xx}}\sum E[(x_i-\bar{x})(\beta_1(x_i-\bar{x})+(u_i-\bar{u}))]\\ &=\frac{1}{S_{xx}}\beta_1 S_{xx}+\sum(x_i-\bar{x})E[u_i|x]-E[\bar{u}|x]\sum(x_i-\bar{x}) \\ &= \beta_1+\sum(x_i-\bar{x})E[u_i|x]\end{align}$$
The second term won't go off when $E[u_i|x]\neq c$ (thanks to the correction by @Laconic), and introduce a bias to the expected value. So, it seems you're right.

Comment: Won’t the second term be zero if E[u|x] is constant?