# Deriving the conditional distributions of a multivariate normal distribution (more than 2)

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance, matrix

(This is a follow up on another question [Deriving the conditional distributions of a multivariate normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution).)

I struggle when I condition several variables on another. My question is how to find the distribution of: $(y_1, y_2|y_3)$ where 
\begin{align}
Y &\sim MVN_3(μ, Σ)  \\[5pt]
\text{where } μ &= (0,0,0)  \\[5pt]
\text{ and covariance matrix is }Σ &= \begin{bmatrix}1 &\rho_{12} &\rho{13}  \\
\rho_{12} &1 &\rho_{23}  \\
\rho_{12} &\rho_{23} &1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Can I use the same form as in the question above?

The other way would also be interesting: $(y_1|y_2, y_3)$...

Comment: Welcome to the site, @edi. I took the liberty of editing your post to use the $\LaTeX$-style markdown our site affords. Please ensure it still says what you want it to say.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. The answer in the linked question implies a completely arbitrary decomposition of $m$ variables in a multivariate Normal distribution into $k$ variables and $m-k$ variables. You're certainly allowed to use that to decompose 3 into 2 and 1.