# Retrodiction / Specific filter to obtain initial state

Tags: maximum-likelihood, repeated-measures, random-variable, measurement-error, kalman-filter

### Problem

I have a system that is measured at regular intervals. The state of the system at those times is given by the vector $\vec x=(x_0, x_1, x_2,\cdots)$. In between each measurement, a random variable $z$, drawn from a Gaussian distribution with zero mean and standard deviation $\sigma_z$ is added onto the state and there is some decay, i.e., $x_i=(1-\gamma)x_{i-1}+z_i$. (The underlying model is a damped harmonic oscillator in a thermal environment, probed at multiples of its period.)

My measurements are imperfect, i.e., I measure $\vec y=(y_0,y_1,y_2,\cdots)$, where $y_i=x_i+d_i$. Again, the $d$ are drawn from a Gaussian distribution of zero mean, with standard deviation $\sigma_d$.
Note that this setup is a close variant of an example on the [Wikipedia page for the Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Example_application,_technical). But as far as I understand, the Kalman filter does not take the whole measurement record into account, but provides an update rule for the best guess. In particular, it's estimate for $x_0$, which I am particularly interested in, is bad.

I would like to find $\vec x$ given some measurement record $\vec y$ (parameters $\sigma_d, \sigma_z$, $\gamma$ are known). I believe I should use some maximum likelihood analysis, but I have trouble finding the right probability distributions for $P(\vec y|\vec x), P(\vec x), P(\vec y)$ that I need to determine $P(\vec x|\vec y)$.

### Attempt

I tried guessing what the right probability distributions should be.
This one is fairly easy:
$$P(\vec y|\vec x) = 
\prod_{i=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_z^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(y_i-x_i)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\right).$$

Now for $P(\vec x)$, I'm already slightly unsure. I start at equilibrium of the above update rule for $x_i$, i.e., when the covariance $\sigma_{x_i}^2\to(1-\gamma)\sigma_{x_{i-1}}^2+\sigma_d^2$ has reached a steady state, i.e., $\sigma_{x_0}=\sigma_d/\sqrt{\gamma}$. This is my expectation for $x_0$.
Thus I think I should write 
$$ P(\vec x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_{x_0}^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{x_0^2}{2\sigma_{x_0}^2}\right)\times\prod_{i=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_d^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x_i-x_{i-1})^2}{2\sigma_d^2}\right). $$

However, the real problem is with $P(\vec y)$, and I think this is due to my limited experience with this method. Naively, without thinking about Bayesian updates, my guess for $P(\vec x|\vec y)$ would have looked like the product of $P(\vec x)$ and $P(\vec y|\vec x)$. 
I think my expectation for $\vec y$ should be
$$ P(\vec y) = \int d\vec x\, P(\vec x)P(\vec y|\vec x). $$
It is possible to do all the Gaussian integrals, but it doesn't seem to give a simple result.

Is there some simpler assumption I can make? And how is it justified? Is there a mistake somewhere else?

### Attempt #2

I'm still not entirely sure about $P(\vec y)$ (I think it's correct though), but one can get by without explicitly calculating it.

One mistake above is calling this approach "maximum likelihood". It's not. MLE would mean that I chose $\vec x$ such that $P(\vec y|\vec x)$ above becomes maximal for a given set of measurement results $\vec y$. This is a bad guess, as it neglects what we know about how the state evolves (note that $\sigma_d$ does not crop up in $P(\vec y|\vec x)$). Instead, what I am doing is Bayesian inference, i.e., finding the conditional probability $P(\vec x|\vec y)$.

To do this, we start with the joint distribution $P(\vec x, \vec y)=P(\vec y|\vec x)P(\vec x)$. This is a normal distribution
$$ \begin{pmatrix}\vec x \\ \vec y\end{pmatrix} \sim 
N\left[\begin{pmatrix}\vec \mu_x \\ \vec \mu_y\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix}\Sigma_{xx} & \Sigma_{xy} \\ \Sigma_{xy} & \Sigma_{yy}\end{pmatrix}\right],$$
with $\mu_x,\mu_y=0$, $\Sigma_{yy} = \Sigma_{xy} = (1/2\sigma_z^2)\mathbb 1$, and
$$ [\Sigma_{xx}]_{ij} = \left( \frac{1}{2\sigma_z^2} + \frac{1}{\sigma_d^2} \right)\delta_{i,j} + \left( \frac{1}{2\sigma_{x_0}^2} - \frac{1}{2\sigma_d^2} \right)\delta_{i,0}\delta_{j,0}+\frac{1}{2\sigma_d^2}(\delta_{i,j+1}+\delta_{i,j-1}).$$
NB: $\Sigma_{xx}$ is tri-diagonal apart from the first element, which differs (indexing from 0).

It's actually straightforward to derive the conditional distribution for $\vec x$ from the joint distribution [[2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution)]. It is given through
$$ \vec x \sim N(\mu_x+\Sigma_{xy}\Sigma_{yy}^{-1}(\vec y-\vec\mu_y), \Sigma_{xx}-\Sigma_{xy}\Sigma_{yy}^{-1}\Sigma_{xy}). $$
However, in our case, this reduces to 
$$ \vec x\sim N( \vec y, \Sigma_{xx}-1/2\sigma_z^2 ),$$
which is not at all what I am expecting. All values of $\vec y$ should be used to determine a specific $x_i$. The problem lies in the fact that $\Sigma_{yy}$ is diagonal. What am I missing?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding your notation or is what you've called $P(\vec x|\vec y)$ not simply the result of the Kalman smoother?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Chris. I'm not sure, I will check it out. If it is it should be derivable as I tried, right? The discussion on Wikipedia is not very clear to me, it would be nice to get some insight by deriving it for this example.

Comment: Yes, but it's easiest to derive recursively rather than all at once, first by computing forward each filtering distribution $p(x_t|y_1,...,y_t)$ from $p(x_{t-1}|y_1,...,y_{t-1})$, and then backwards the state posteriors $p(x_{t-1}|y_1,...,y_T)$ from $p(x_t|y_1,...,y_T)$. To be sure, do you *really* have an observation $y_0$ that corresponds to the state $x_0$ that you care about (as you've written)? Typically the "initial state" is the time right before the first observation, and inference about it is not quite the same.

Comment: **a)** I've tried to understand the derivation of the Kalman smoother, but in vain. In the end, I need an analytical formula for $x_0$, which is why I was trying to derive it myself. **b)** I have added a second attempt to solve the problem, which seems to almost get me there, but I must be missing something small. Maybe you can spot it?

**c)** And yes, I do have an observation $y_0$. It doesn't strike me as unusual. The difference is small anyway, waiting a while to make the first measurement just changes the expected initial variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted attempt is almost correct, but it incorrectly identifies the covariance of the joint normal distribution.

### Joint Normal Distribution

Given
$$P(\vec y|\vec x) = 
\prod_{i=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_z^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(y_i-x_i)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\right).$$
and
$$ P(\vec x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_{x_0}^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{x_0^2}{2\sigma_{x_0}^2}\right)\times\prod_{i=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_d^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x_i-x_{i-1})^2}{2\sigma_d^2}\right), $$
we can write
$$ P(\vec x,\vec y)=P(\vec x)P(\vec y|\vec x)\propto \exp\left(-\frac12 (\vec x^\top,\vec y^\top)\mathsf Q\begin{pmatrix}\vec x\\\vec y\end{pmatrix}\right), $$
where $\mathsf Q$ has the entries that I thought above where the covariance 
matrix, i.e.,
$\mathsf Q_{yy} = \mathsf Q_{xy} = (1/2\sigma_z^2)\mathbb 1$, and
$$ [\mathsf Q_{xx}]_{ij} = \left( \frac{1}{2\sigma_z^2} + \frac{1}{\sigma_d^2} \right)\delta_{i,j} + \left( \frac{1}{2\sigma_{x_0}^2} - \frac{1}{2\sigma_d^2} \right)\delta_{i,0}\delta_{j,0}+\frac{1}{2\sigma_d^2}(\delta_{i,j+1}+\delta_{i,j-1}).$$

### Covariance Matrix

In contrast to what is stated above, the covariance matrix $\mathsf\Sigma=\mathsf Q^{-1}$. This is easily done with [block matrix inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion).
We find
$$ \mathsf\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\mathsf\Sigma_{xx} & -\mathsf\Sigma_{xx} \\ -\mathsf\Sigma_{xx} & 2\sigma_z^2+\mathsf\Sigma_{xx}\end{pmatrix},$$
where
$$ \mathsf\Sigma_{xx}=(\mathsf Q_{xx}-1/(2\sigma_z^2))^{-1}. $$

### Conditional distribution

Given this, the conditional distribution for $\vec x$ can be derived from the joint distribution [[2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution)]
$$ \vec x \sim N(\mu_x+\mathsf\Sigma_{xy}\mathsf\Sigma_{yy}^{-1}(\vec y-\vec\mu_y), \mathsf\Sigma_{xx}-\mathsf\Sigma_{xy}\mathsf\Sigma_{yy}^{-1}\mathsf\Sigma_{xy}). $$

### Analytical solution

I think the matrix $\mathsf Q_{xx}$ can be inverted analytically, or at least to a very good approximation. I will include this once I have done so.