# Conditional variance of ARMA(p,q) process

Tags: time-series, arima

$X_t$ is an ARMA(p,q) process. How do you derive the conditional variance on $X_s$ $\forall s<t$, i.e
$$Var({X_t|X_s, s<t})=?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a standard procedure, but I think this should work:

Starting from the representation $\theta (B) X = \phi (B) \epsilon$ for $X \sim \operatorname{ARMA}(p,q)$, let's assume we know the roots of $\phi(z)$ (these are usually computed anyway), then we can represent $\phi(B) = c \prod_{k=1}^q (B - \lambda_k )$, and then using the Neumann series $$ (B - \lambda)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-\lambda)^{-k-1} B^k , $$
we get the $\operatorname{AR}(\infty)$-representation
$$ \frac{\theta (B)}{\phi (B)} X=\epsilon \\
\left( c^{-1} \theta(B)\prod_{k = 1}^q \sum_{n_k=0}^\infty  (- \lambda_k)^{-n_k - 1} B^{n_k} \right) X = \epsilon \\
c^{-1}  \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left( \sum_{n_1 + \cdots + n_q = n} \prod_{k=1}^q (- \lambda_k )^{-n_k-1} \right) B^{n} \theta(B)  X = \epsilon .
$$

This should be no problem to evaluate this numerically for some orders of $n$ up to $m$. Then, given such an $\operatorname{AR}(m)$ approximation $\widetilde \theta (B) X \approx \epsilon$, you can compute the conditional variance in a straight-forward manner:
$$X_{t+h} \vert \mathcal F_t = \dots + \epsilon_{t+h} + \widetilde \theta_1 \epsilon_{t+h-1} + (\widetilde \theta_1^2 + \widetilde \theta_2) \epsilon_{t+h - 2} + (\widetilde \theta_3 + \widetilde \theta_2 \widetilde \theta_1 + \widetilde \theta_1 \widetilde \theta_2 + \widetilde \theta_1^3) \epsilon_{t+h-3} + \dots ,  $$
yielding the conditional variance
$$\operatorname{var}(X_{t+h} \vert \mathcal F_t ) = \sigma_\epsilon^2 \left\lbrace \widetilde \theta_1^2 + (\widetilde \theta_1^2 + \widetilde \theta_2)^2 + (\widetilde \theta_3 + \widetilde \theta_2 \widetilde \theta_1 + \widetilde \theta_1 \widetilde \theta_2^2 + \widetilde \theta_1^3)^2 + \dots \right\rbrace $$
(terms up to $(\widetilde \theta_h + \widetilde \theta_{h-1} \widetilde  \theta_1 + \dots)^2$)

Comment: This has the potential to be a good answer, but I have given it (-1) for now.  The main problem here is that the substance of the answer is glossed over with "no problem to evaluate this numerically" and "compute in a straightforward manner".  I think that most readers on this site will need more guidance on those steps in order to implement this method.  If you can edit to improve then I will happily remove my downvote and replace with an upvote.  (An example implementing it would also be wonderful if possible.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple formula for this, but the variance can be computed using known algorithms.  You can find an algorithm for computing the auto-covariance in [Brockwell and Davis (1991)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387974293) (Section 3.3).  Assuming you are working with a Gaussian ARMA process, this can be used to find the conditional variance using standard results for the [conditional variance of the multivariate normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/).

You can compute the conditional covariance matrix for the Gaussian ARMA process using the `ARMA.var` function in the [`ts.extend` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ts.extend) in `R`.  This package also contains broader probability functions for stationary Gaussian ARMA processes.  Here is an example of the conditional variance matrix for a Gaussian $\text{ARMA}(2,3)$ process where we condition on the value at time $s=1$ and determine the conditional variance matrix over times $t=2,3,4,5$.

```
#Set the parameters for an ARMA process
AR <- c(0.8, 0.1)
MA <- c(0.6, 0.4, 0.4)

#Set conditioning values
N <- 5
CONDVALS <- rep(NA, N)
CONDVALS[1] <- 6

#Compute the conditional variance
library(ts.extend)
ARMA.var(n = N, condvals = CONDVALS, ar = AR, ma = MA)

         Time[2]  Time[3]  Time[4]   Time[5]
Time[2] 1.401380 1.996988 2.309347  2.447176
Time[3] 1.996988 3.940649 4.793826  5.189126
Time[4] 2.309347 4.793826 6.949907  7.847309
Time[5] 2.447176 5.189126 7.847309 10.019159
```