# Question about the conditional distribution of a sub-vector of a multivariate normal vector

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, multivariate-normal-distribution

For a multivariate normal vector $\mathbf{x} = (\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \mathbf{x}_3, \mathbf{x}_4)$ with mean 0 and variance $\mathbf{\Sigma} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{\Sigma}_{11} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{12} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{13} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{14} \\ \mathbf{\Sigma}_{21} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{22} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{23} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{24} \\ \mathbf{\Sigma}_{31} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{32} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{33} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{34} \\ \mathbf{\Sigma}_{41} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{42} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{43} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{44} \end{bmatrix}$, is it true that

1. $(\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_3)$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{\Sigma}_{11} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{13} \\ \mathbf{\Sigma}_{31} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{33} \end{bmatrix}$?
2. $\mathbf{x}_3 | \mathbf{x}_1$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{33} - \mathbf{\Sigma}_{31} \mathbf{\Sigma}_{11}^{-1} \mathbf{\Sigma}_{13}$?

I believe (1) is true because of the accepted answer at [Deriving the conditional distributions of a multivariate normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution). I think (2) follows from (1), if (1) is true. However, I wonder why (1) is true - I guess (1) could be verified mathematically by integrating out $\mathbf{x}_2, \mathbf{x}_4$?

Comment: The computational part of $(1)$ is trivial: it is obtained by ignoring the other two components $x_2$ and $x_4.$  In short, you just write down what you know about the variable $(x_1,x_3).$ This would work regardless of the 4-variate distribution.  The only content of $(1)$ is to assert that $(x_1,x_3)$ has a binormal distribution.  One demonstration exhibits $(x_1,x_3)$ as a linear transformation of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4),$ because linear transformations of Normal variables have Normal distributions.

Comment: @whuber Thank you so much! The idea of using linear transformation (projection) for (1) is very smart.