# Derivative of multivariate normal cdf with respect to it’s arguments

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution, derivative

I'm using a result from the dissertation of Poddar(2016, [link](https://digitalcommons.odu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=mathstat_etds)) and he states the following in his appendix A1: We will use the well known property, stated here for completeness, of the multivariate normal distribution

[image]

Since this results in negative variances in my code, I'm wondering whether this is correct. No reference to the property was given by Poddar.

Comment: Result (52) is standard, [as discussed on this forum.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30600/7224) Please correct the title into *derivation* as *derivative* has another meaning.

Comment: Also. Please correct the surname of the author, in question, in the post.

Comment: Consult any standard multivariate text: Anderson, Muirhead for this standard result.

Comment: at a guess your negative values are to do with numerical stability.  computers only have finite precision (that's part of the reason they're so fast) and hence you need to structure your algorithms in a way to exploit this.  https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/26/comparing-three-methods-of-computing-standard-deviation/ seems somewhat relevant, although only for scalars

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.