# What is the multivariate distribution of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n | X_1+ \dotsm + X_n = y)$?

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, multivariate-normal-distribution

What is the multivariate distribution of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n | X_1+ \dotsm + X_n = y)$, given $y$ and that $X_i$ is (otherwise; without being given $y$) unconditionally independently normally distributed with mean $\mu $ and standard deviation $\sigma$?

And, to the task at hand: How do I simulate random drawings of $X$ given $y,~ \mu,$ and $\sigma$?

Comment: Please just apply any of the formulas for conditional Normal distributions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+conditional+variance.  The application is direct and simple, because $(X_1,\ldots, X_n, X_1+\cdots+X_n)$ has an $(n+1)$-variate Normal distribution whose parameters are particularly easy to compute from the independence of the $X_i.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @whuber, we can simply use the known formulas for conditional distributions in the multinormal, as given for instance at [Deriving the conditional distributions of a multivariate normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution) (we will use notation from there).  At first I doubted, since the full covariance matrix $\Sigma$ in this case is singular, but a close reading of the [proof](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30600/11887) by user macro shows that we only need that $\Sigma_{22}$ is non-singular. That $\Sigma$ itself is singular does not matter.

For this case, we can easily compute (details not given) that
$$
\Sigma =\begin{pmatrix} \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \\
                        \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}
         \end{pmatrix}
       =\sigma^2 \begin{pmatrix}I_n & 1_n \\
                                  1_n^T & n  \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, and $1_n$ is the column vector with $n$  $1$'s. Then using the formulas we find that the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y=y$, where $Y=\sum_1^n X_i$, is the n-dimensional multinormal distribution with mean
$$ \mu_{x|y} = 1_n \frac{y}n $$ that is, all the components have the same conditional expectation $y/n$, and covariance matrix
$$ \Sigma_{x|y} = \sigma^2 \begin{pmatrix} I_n - 1_n 1_n^T / n
    \end{pmatrix} $$
Note that $1_n 1_n^T$ is an $n \times n$-matrix with all components 1.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if the extension to vectors is straightforward, so here's that question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/609277/370545

Comment: I don't follow that, because the present question is *explicitly* about vectors!  Moreover, the method of this answer and the formula it relies on apply *without any modification whatsoever* to your new question.

Comment: @whuber Scalars, vectors, matrices... What I meant was one more dimension. And I did not have too much trouble implementing the above answer, but I am having a terrible time implementing it for the higher-dimensional case. :(

Comment: It's unclear what you might mean by "one more dimension," because all it means is -- the vectors are of a different dimension.  But since this answer applies to *all* dimensions, it applies to any situation you might contemplate.

Comment: @whuber This question (above) asks about $X_i$s that are scalars (and $X$ thus being a vector). The other question asks about $X_i$s that are vectors. So, in that question the $X$s are either matrices or vectors of vectors. I'm sure that the above answer provides the necessary clues on how to handle this, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: This question asks about an $X$ that is explicitly a *vector.*  Any bunch of vectors is, according to the axioms, *also a vector.*  Your $y$ here is also a (dimension 1) *vector.*  Proceed from there.

Comment: @whuber OK, that is good to know (about the axioms). Thanks! But whereas the unconditional distributions of the $X_i$s are independent, they are not in the other question. To (hopefully) clarify: in the above question, the unconditional $X$  represents one time series (of length $n$). In the other question the unconditional $X$ represents a bunch of time series that have a covariance (matrix, I dare to say).

Comment: Right: and you just plug in the entries of that covariance matrix where needed and the remaining ones are given by the independence assumption.

Comment: @whuber I'm giving it a shot (in the other question).